# variable scope in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access the value of a variable that is set inside a `.click` function outside of the function but I'll get the error, can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var id;
var currentPosition;
var slideWidth = 368;
var slides;
var numberOfSlides;

$('#accordion_catering h3').click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' +id+'_gallery').show();
    //alert(id);//works
});
alert(id); // is undefined

// Because id is undefined these don't work .

slides = $('.' + id + '_slide');
numberOfSlides = slides.length;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click did not occure yet, so id is not set ... it's not about variable-scopes, more about events and their handlers :)

*as you added a cmt, i adapted my solution as following:*

```
var currentPosition;
var slideWidth = 368;
var slides;
var numberOfSlides;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var element = $('#accordion_catering h3');
    element.click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        DisplayGallery(id);
    });
    element.trigger('click'); // maybe you want to trigger it
});
function DisplayGallery(id) {
    $('#' + id +'_gallery').show();
    slides = $('.' + id + '_slide');
    numberOfSlides = slides.length;
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, the reason I set the id in the click function was because I'm showing different galleries based on the id, so I get the value of id once is clicked and show the corresponding gallery, also there's different number of slides within each gallery, that's why the numberOfSlides needs to be connected to that particular id inside the clickvfunction

Answer (score 3):

id will only be set when the click event handler is run at least once, because you're setting the id variable inside the event handler

Answer (score 0):

```
var id;  
var currentPosition;  
var slideWidth = 368;  
var slides;  
var numberOfSlides;  
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#accordion_catering h3').click(function() { 
        id = $(this).attr('id'); 
        $('#' +id+'_gallery').show(); 
        //alert(id);//works 
        slides = $('.' + id + '_slide'); 
        numberOfSlides = slides.length; 
    }); 
    $('#accordion_catering h3').trigger('click');
    alert(id); // is defined 
)};
```

So, basically, do not access id until this event has fired, it will then be set.